# Are there any nontrivial near-isometries of the $n$-dimensional cube?

Tags: inequalities, permanent

Consider the $n$-dimensional Hamming cube, $C = \{-1,1\}^n$.  Given an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix $O$, I'll measure "how close $O$ is to being an isometry of $C$" by the following scoring function:

$s(O) = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{x\in C}\left| \prod_{i=1}^{n} (Ox)_i \right|.$

Intuitively, $s(O)$ measures how close the image of each $x\in C$ is to belonging in $C$, averaged over all $x\in C$.  It's not hard to see that $s(O)\le 1$ for all $O$, with equality if and only if $O$ is just a product of reflections and permutations of the $n$ coordinates (i.e., "trivial").  My question is the following:

**If $s(O)$ is non-negligibly large (say, $\ge n^{-O(1)}$), then must $O$ be "close" to a product of reflections and permutations of the coordinates?**

Here, by "close," I mean that $O$ contains some diagonal whose product is at least $n^{-O(1)}$ in absolute value.

I should mention that my summer student Sumegha Garg did a computer search for interesting examples of such $O$, for $n$ up to about $10$, but didn't find much.  When $n=4$, the Hadamard matrix does fairly well, achieving $s(O)=1/2$, but we've checked that $s(O)$ decreases exponentially with $n$ for $n\times n$ Fourier and Hadamard matrices and tensor products thereof.

A few words about where this question came from: it's not hard to show that the *permanent* of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ can be expressed in the following form (the so-called "Glynn formula").

$\operatorname{Per}(A) = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{x\in C} \prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i (Ax)_i $.

So in particular, we have $\left|\operatorname{Per}(A)\right| \le s(A)$, and if $O$ is orthogonal, then $\left|\operatorname{Per}(O)\right| \le s(O) \le 1$, with equality achieved if and only if $O$ is a product of reflections and permutations of the coordinates.  Now, for reasons arising from linear-optical quantum computing, my student Alex Arkhipov and I would like to know whether there are any $n\times n$ orthogonal matrices $O$ satisfying $\left|\operatorname{Per}(O)\right| \ge n^{-O(1)}$, which are far from the "trivial" examples---i.e., reflections and permutations of the coordinates.  (Actually, we'd like to know the answer for unitary matrices, but if we don't even know it for real orthogonal matrices, then we might as well start there.)  And this naturally led to the stronger conjecture that there isn't even any nontrivial rotation $O$ of the Hamming cube that produces a large value of $s(O)$.

As a final remark, Arkhipov managed to show that, if $O$ is orthogonal and $\left|\operatorname{Per}(O)\right| \ge \sqrt{1-1/e}$, then $O$ is close to a product of reflections and permutations of the coordinates.  I'm not sure whether his proof generalizes to all $O$ such that $s(O) \ge \sqrt{1-1/e}$.  In any case, the techniques don't seem to generalize to $s(O) \ge n^{-O(1)}$.

**Update:** Sumegha Garg notes that, if we consider $n\times n$ unitary matrices $U$ rather than just real orthogonal matrices $O$, then there *is* a way to get $s(U)=1$, despite $U$ not containing any diagonal whose product is $n^{-O(1)}$ in absolute value.  The way to do it is to let $U$ be block-diagonal, with $2\times 2$ blocks of the form

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{cc}%
1 & i\\
1 & -i
\end{array}
\right)  $.

On the other hand, this is essentially the *only* counterexample we know, and even in the complex case, the conjecture could easily be reformulated to account for it.

Comment: Nice question!  A model question: if $Ox$ lies _exactly_ in the unit cube $\{-1,+1\}^n$ for $n^{-100}$ of the $x$'s, does this force $O$ to be an approximate cube symmetry?  Your situation is close to this, except that rather than exactly lying in the unit cube, all but $O(\log n)$ of the coefficients of $Ox$ lie within $0.0001$ of $\{+1,-1\}$ (together with some similar assertions of this nature).  It's possible that some additive combinatorics or some Blum-Luby-Rubinfeld type arguments can be used to improve this structure, though $\{-1,+1\}^n$ isn't additively closed, which is a problem.

Comment: It occurs to me that inverse Littlewood-Offord theory (see e.g. Ch7 of my book with Van Vu) is likely to be helpful.  Note that for most i, the distribution of $(Ox)_i$, with $x$ drawn uniformly from the discrete cube, is concentrated at $\pm 1$, which by ILO theory gives strong constraints on the coefficients of the i^th row of O (most of the entries must lie very close to a generalised arithmetic progression).  By using multidimensional ILO and working with several i simultaneously, one should be able to cut down the possibilities further.

Comment: Terry: Thanks so much; that's an extremely helpful suggestion! (And you may have just earned a customer for your book. :) ) The one thing that worries me here is the need to rule out massive, conspiratorial correlations among the various entries of $Ox$. I.e., even if there's only a $1/\sqrt{n}$ probability that some $(Ox)_i$ is $\pm 1$, if conditioned on that happening the other $(Ox)_i$'s were *also* $\pm 1$ then we'd be in trouble. I suppose that's why you mentioned the need for "multidimensional" ILO.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a reference to this question, the matrices with large permanent must in fact be close to trivial.  See [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.07474).